# I want to automatically update my sql table data after 20 days from stored date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/299Vv.png)

I have this table in My SQl. I wants to change the column "Status" from 'Pending' to 'Defaulter' after 20 days from "rec_date" column automatically.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use an Event for that that fires regulary and checks the dates.

Comment: If you have shell access you could setup a cron job. I think some shared webhosts also offer cron job support these days

Comment: More info on events in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html If that doesnt work out (to limited), then you can always make the php cronjob that can do all manner of checks and balances on a timed interval.

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of your table(s), without which it's hard to give a good answer.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's answer it in a generic way, to create a cronjob in an easy way.

1. Create .php file (ex.php)
2. Do what ever the logic, you want here like select from the db the records where "rec_date" > 20
3. Update the database status
4. to run the php file, simply from terminal type:
    **php ex.php**
5. You need to run this php ex.php in a cronjob (on server, or locally) and specify the time like every 5mins run the ex.php file

Answer (score 1):

Create a proc and Run it on schedule

```
CREATE PROC ProcNameHere
AS 

BEGIN   

DECLARE @datetime DATETIME
SET @datetime = CURDATE()

UPDATE tablename 
SET [Status] = 'Defaulter'
WHERE rec_date < DATEADD(DAY, -20,@datetime) 
       AND [Status] <> 'Defaulter'

       END
```

Comment: this is invalid MySQL code.. MySQL doesnt support function `GETDATE()` and brackets

Comment: replace it with CURDATE()

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger and event scheduler which initiates after 20 days